# Translate a JS project to a TypeScript one

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, module

I have a project (a web interface) organized like this:

```
    Directory: L:\root-of-project


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       16/01/2019     11:25                .git
d-----       16/01/2019     11:38                node_modules
d-----       16/01/2019     11:25                src
-a----       16/01/2019     11:07            403 package.json
-a----       20/12/2018     17:13           2541 README.md
-a----       ...[OTHER FILES]...


    Directory: L:\root-of-project\src


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       16/01/2019     11:10                main
d-----       16/01/2019     09:32                static
-a----       16/01/2019     11:25          23274 index.html


    Directory: L:\root-of-project\src\main


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       16/01/2019     11:10                a-folder-with-js-files
d-----       16/01/2019     11:10                another-folder-with-js-files
d-----       ...[OTHER DIRECTORIES]...
d-----       16/01/2019     11:25                vue-components-folder
-a----       16/01/2019     11:08           5673 file1.js
-a----       15/01/2019     16:24           2830 file2.ts
-a----       ...[OTHER FILES]...


    Directory: L:\root-of-project\src\main\vue-components-folder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       16/01/2019     11:10                a-vue-component-folder
d-----       16/01/2019     11:10                another-vue-component-folder
d-----       ...[OTHER DIRCTORIES]...


    Directory: L:\root-of-project\src\main\vue-components-folder\a-vue-component-folder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       15/01/2019     21:16            389 a-vue-component.interface.ts
-a----       15/01/2019     16:14           4892 a-vue-component.js
-a----       15/01/2019     13:36            576 style.css
```

And I am trying to translate its files from JavaScript to Typescript, but I am aving some difficulties with using Typescript with Vue.js and some other difficulties with modules: when i translate a typescript module, it is not read by the browser because it complains that all the modules must be placed in the same directory as index.html (the error I get is similar to this one `import statement may only appear at the top level`).

(Some files in the list above are already .ts because the do not include dependencies to other files)

Which approach shoould I follow in order to continue using multiple files divided in multiple folders with TypeScript?
(For more info, the project is hosted [here](https://github.com/Pastello/Kathara-SDN-Interface). I am using VS Code for developement)

Answer (score 0):

> when i translate a typescript module, it is not read by the browser because it complains that all the modules must be placed in the same directory as index.html

You shouldn't publish modules to the browser. Instead you should use something like webpack (https://webpack.js.org/) to bundle them for the browser.

Since you have a fullstack app, you will need to compile the TS twice:
* Once for node.js using tsc
* Once for browser using webpack

## Additional Resources

- [I also have a free video on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QeBGnmo1ieo).

Comment: When I add webpack to my project I loose all the variables' names and functions' ones. As they are bound to html element which reference them it's a big problem for me.